# Firebase Analytics Event does not support array parameters error

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I specially created an event in firebase analytics. I am getting an error

```
        Bundle item1 = new Bundle();
        item1.putString(Param.ITEM_ID, "item1");

        Bundle item2 = new Bundle();
        item1.putString(Param.ITEM_ID, "item2");

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("eventCategory", "Ecommerce");
        params.putParcelableArray(Param.ITEMS, new Parcelable[] {item1, item2});
        analytics.logEvent("testEvent", params);
```

When I make a request like above; I get the error "**Event does not support array parameters**". Can you help me please?